# parse email address from HTML in objective c

Tags: html, objective-c, parsing

This is the HTML from which I just need to get "user@website.com".

```
<td valign="top">                                                       

<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    PrintMail('user','website.com','user<at>website.com', '  '); 
/* ]]> */
</script><a href="JavaScript:SendMail('user','website.com');" onmouseover="self.status='user@website.com'; return true;" onmouseout="self.status=''; return true;">user@website.com</a><br>
```

Here is my code:

```
NSArray *emailNodes = [bodyNode findChildTags:@"td"];


    for (HTMLNode *inputNode in emailNodes) {
        if ([inputNode findChildrenWithAttribute:@"valign" matchingName:@"top" allowPartial:NO]) {

                NSLog(@"%@", [[inputNode getAttributeNamed:@"href"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]);
```

HTML parser I am using you can find here: https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser

I modified my code million times by using first child, next sibling and so on, but nothing...

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Regex for email extraction for exp:

```
NSString *regex = @"[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})";
for (NSString *match in [html componentsSeperatedByRegex: regex]{
    NSLog (@"%@", match); 
}
```